# change form address of sending mail via godaddy.com

Tags: php, email, hosting

i am using the code to send mail via php

```
$to = $_POST['userId'];
                    $subject = "New password received";
                     $body = 'Your new password is '.'"'.$newPass.'"';
                     if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
                      mail. Please check your mail!</p>");
                        $succ = 'Password successfully sent to your mail. Please check your mail!';
                      } else {

                       $err = 'Password delivery failed!';
                      }
```

now mail is going to the user. but from address is coming as they configure in host(godaddy.com). now how to change the form address in host(godaddy),so that i can get desire from address in received mail?

thanks..

Comment: Sidenote: sending a clear text password is not really good practice, mails are not a safe channel

Comment: +1 @DamienPirsy ; Op, you should consider writing a longer and most structured message so this does not get flagged as spam.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to change the adress this mail is sent from? If yes, check the mail-documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php . You have to add a 4th parameter in your mail-function. This passes the headers of the mail.

```
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$subject = "New password received";
$body = 'Your new password is '.'"'.$newPass.'"';
if (mail($_POST['userId'], $subject, $body, $headers)) {
    $succ = 'Password successfully sent to your mail. Please check your mail!';
} else {
    $err = 'Password delivery failed!';
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. its working. i have one question, what does reply-to means? if i give any invalid from,Reply-To email, it is going to user.

Comment: Thank you @user989184, please accept my answer. Reply-to means the address the mailreader will fill out if the user clicks reply. Usually you send this mail from newpassword@yoursite.com, forgottenpassword@yoursite.com or donotreply@yoursite.com. And have your correct mailadress under reply to. for example post@yoursite.com.

Answer (score 0):

add this

```
$headers = "From: kdaniel@aosepc.com\n";

if (mail($to, $subject, $body,$headers)) {
```